# @Input() is undefined

Tags: angular, input, angular-material, angular10

I have 2 function in my angular component,  first is for  table and second  returns list which is  for  child component.   I call  second  one function  firstly, but @Input is undefined.  Also  I try to call that function in child component , but  there is  also undefined. Below is two photo of my problem. OperationTypesFilter  is for input.  If I  set value  to operationTypesFilter
It works.

checkbox-filter.component.html

```
<ul class="pl-1">
    <li *ngFor="let filter of filters; index as i">
        <mat-checkbox color="primary" (change)="onItemSelect(filter,i)" [(ngModel)]="filter.checked">
            {{ filter.value | translate }}
        </mat-checkbox>
    </li>
</ul>
```

checkbox-filter.component.ts

```
this.list.forEach((item, id) => {
      this.filters.push({ id: item.id, value: item.name, checked: false })
    });
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't add your code as image, add the code in the question itself. And what exactly is not working?

Comment: Thank you for your advicce.  In app checkbox component   doesn't show  list. I will edit my post and  write checkboxfilter component  html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**: `OperationTypesFilter` is undefined because it is not set & is waiting to be set in `subscribe`,

**solution**:

1. if it is required before loading the child component add a *ngIf="OperationTypesFilter" so it only loads when the value is available.
2. if it will work with an empty array as well, set it to `[]` initially till the response comes back.